# Is it possible to limit a Linux process so that it can only run on a particular core on a particular machine?

Tags: linux, unix, central-processing-unit, multi-threading

Let's say I have a quad-core box and four identical processes, each with ten threads. Is it possible, in Linux, to say that Process A is only allowed to run on CPU 0, Process B is only allowed to run on CPU 1, etc?

Answer (score 16):

```
taskset <affinity mask> -p <process>
```

i.e.

```
taskset 1 -p 12345
```

to set process 12345 to use only processor/core 1

The bitmask can be a list (i.e. 1,3,4 to use cores 1 3 and 4 of a 4+ core system) or a bitmask in hex (0x0000000D the 1,3,4, 0x00000001 for just core 1)

`taskset` is usually in a package called `shedutils`.

Edit: almost forgot... If you want to set the affinity of a new command instead of change it for an existing process, use:

```
taskset <mask> <program> [<arg1>]...[<argN>]
```

Answer (score 1):

taskset (util-linux 2.13-pre7)
usage: taskset [options] [mask | cpu-list] [pid | cmd [args...]]
set or get the affinity of a process

-p, --pid                  operate on existing given pid
  -c, --cpu-list             display and specify cpus in list format
  -h, --help                 display this help
  -v, --version              output version information

The default behavior is to run a new command:
  taskset 03 sshd -b 1024
You can retrieve the mask of an existing task:
  taskset -p 700
Or set it:
  taskset -p 03 700
List format uses a comma-separated list instead of a mask:
  taskset -pc 0,3,7-11 700
Ranges in list format can take a stride argument:
  e.g. 0-31:2 is equivalent to mask 0x55555555

you can alway optimize you server as u r need