# How to limit a webapp to a certain number of CPU cores

Tags: tomcat, java, jboss, weblogic, websphere

I need to set a webapp to run on a certain number of cores/ or all of them, on the server(depending on configuration).
The webapp will be running on any one of the following application server's.

```
Apache Tomcat
Weblogic
webspere 7.0 or higher
Jboss 4 or higher
```

Comment: I would expect this to be a function of the various operating systems, not of the JEE servers themselves. Maybe, maybe some JVMs might have options to support it on some OSes, but that's just a guess. There are a bunch of web search results about limiting processes to cores, and they seem to be OS-specific.

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for:
http://serverfault.com/questions/32322/is-it-possible-to-limit-a-linux-process-so-that-it-can-only-run-on-a-particular